# How to handle unique constraint in Entity (AggregateRoot) in Lagom?

Tags: event-sourcing, lagom

In our case we are creating a Ticket entity and in that Email Id has to be unique, how to achieve this using the Lagom Framework?

Comment: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/

Comment: Understood , thanks